# Handling POST of json data in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have an external application POSTing the following JSON data to my website:

```
{  
"version":"1.0",
"data":{
    "videoName":"video name here"   
  }
}
```

The application has a test tool, it seems to return the following:

```
{"payload":"{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"data\":{\"videoName\":\"video name here"\}}
```

when I do a:

```
$input = Request::all();
return $input;
```

However I can't seem to access this JSON object. It's possible I'm being silly as I haven't stepped away to look at this I am however getting very frustrated, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you `json_decode($input)` ?

Comment: Have you included csrf_token sent with your JSON request?

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't seem to access this JSON object"? Access in what way? Provide some code.

Comment: as @TheAlpha said, `json_decode($input)`

Comment: @cen Doing json_decode($input) gives a HTTP status of 500, if I for example do var_dump($input['payload']); I get: string(521) "{"version":"1.0",data":{"videoName":"video name here"}} returned.

Comment: Works just fine to me: http://pastebin.com/yupDuyCE The $input print you provided is not a valid json. Instead of Request:all() you should Request:get() the correct key and decode that instead.